# scalatra not displaying views that match routes correctly

Tags: scala, pug, scalatra

I'm getting started with scalatra and jade, but my views which match a route come
 wrapped in `<pre></pre>` tags.
My project is setup like so:

```
//ScalatraServlet.scala
def get("/index") {
  jade("index")
}

//WEB-INF/templates/views/index.jade
h1 Indexing.

//WEB-INF/templates/views/no_route.jade
h1 works correctly!
```

If I hit `localhost:8080/index` on the browser, it shows the whole html structure inside `<pre></pre>` tags, but if I hit `localhost:8080/test`, which doesn't have a route defined for it in scalatra, it renders correctly.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a caveat to working with routes and jade?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the contentType before calling jade(...) ?

```
def get("/index") {
  contentType="text/html"
  jade("index")
}
```